# Costmap2d inflation radius

Tags: navigation, move-base, costmap-2d-ros, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been trying to increase the inflation radius of obstacles in the local_costmap for `move_base`. The problem that I've noticed is that the inflation radius as viewed by `Costmap2dPublisher` never changes. Using `rosparam get`, I verified that the `inflation_radius` parameter was correctly set, but even setting this value as high as 10m has no effect. It seems that the inflation radius of the obstacles is directly linked to the circumscribed radius of the robot footprint.

If I set the robot footprint to a 0.5m x 0.5m box, the inflation radius is 0.25m. If I set the robot footprint to a 0.8m x 0.8m box, the inflation radius is 0.4m. From the documentation on `costmap_2d`, it seemed that I could set my own inflation radius, but I've been unable to do so.

I would like to be able to set two different values for the `footprint` and the `inflation_radius`. How can I go about doing so?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12874/costmap2d-inflation-radius/) by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11163 on 2012-02-03

Post score: 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had similar confusion when I first went to configure the costmap to inflate differently.

The `inflation_radius` is actually the radius to which the cost scaling function is applied, not a parameter of the cost scaling function. Inside the inflation radius, the cost scaling function is applied, but outside the inflation radius, the cost of a cell is not inflated using the cost function.

Take a look at the documentation for the `cost_scaling_factor`. What you have to do is basically solve the equation there ( `exp(-1.0 * cost_scaling_factor * (distance_from_obstacle - inscribed_radius)) * (costmap_2d::INSCRIBED_INFLATED_OBSTACLE - 1)`) for the correct `cost_scaling_factor`, using your distance from obstacle and the cost value you want that cell to have.

You'll have to make sure to set the inflation radius large enough that it includes the distance you need the cost function to be applied out to, as anything outside the `inflation_radius` will not have the cost function applied.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2012-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 13

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-02-06**:
I'm not sure where you can get the inscribed_radius directly, since it's calculated from the robot footprint. It might get printed as a debug statement somewhere. I think I just calculated it by hand. Might be useful to open a ticket to print out debugs with this if costmap_2d doesn't already.

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-02-03**:
That makes sense. Where can I obtain the value of "inscribed_radius"? Also, is there a way to get Rviz to account for this change? While I can see the cost values changing (by accessing the costmap directly), Rviz still limits inflation to the size of the robot footprint.